# Apache Camel 2.10.2, Spring and Quartz: A route has no processor

Tags: spring, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have a strange behaviour with a Quartz triggered cron route. Whenever I define an hourly cron job everything works fine.

```
<route id="kunden.xml.generate.quartz">
    <from uri="quartz://kunden.xml.generate.quartz?cron=0+0+0/1+*+*+?"/>
    <bean ref="kundenXmlExportDataBuilderService" method="generateKundenXmls"/>
</route>
```

With fine I mean the method *generateKundenXmls* gets called. But If I change the cron expression in order to run it ever 2nd hour on minute 35 cron trigger fires but the method does not get called.

```
<route id="kunden.xml.generate.quartz">
    <from uri="quartz://kunden.xml.generate.quartz?cron=0+35+0/2+*+*+?"/>
    <bean ref="kundenXmlExportDataBuilderService" method="generateKundenXmls"/>
</route>
```

I think I have located the reason why the method does not get called but I have no idea what is going wrong. Camel uses a [RoundRobinLoadBalancer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.10.2/org/apache/camel/processor/loadbalancer/RoundRobinLoadBalancer.java/) to [choose the processor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.10.2/org/apache/camel/processor/loadbalancer/QueueLoadBalancer.java#QueueLoadBalancer). It calls [getProcessors()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.10.2/org/apache/camel/processor/loadbalancer/LoadBalancerSupport.java#LoadBalancerSupport.getProcessors%28%29) but it returns an empty list and therefore does not call my Spring bean.

Does anyone know such a behaviour and can give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: i don't know if you got this already.... but try */2 instead of 0/2